# Correct approach to MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to understand what's the best way to work with a viewmodel and with the model that stays behind.

My model is a collection of custom items (like a list of user configurations).

I understand that the correct way to expose this model is through a `ConfigurationListViewModel` that converts the model's list in data readable by the ui.

But how should I manage the items that lies behind the `ConfigurationListViewModel`?
Should the single configuration itself have a `ConfigurationViewModel`?
Or the main `ConfigurationListViewModel` should handle the exposure of its items?

If I want to add a Configuration to my `ConfigurationList`, I call an `Add()` method to my `ConfigurationListViewModel`, and it creates in itself a new `Configuration`, or should I create a new (`Configuration`? `ConfigurationViewModel`?) in the parent, and then call an `Add`([`Configuration`?`ConfigurationViewModel`?]`newConf)`?

Comment: See http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/02/09/mvvm-to-wrap-or-not-to-wrap.aspx

Comment: MVVM does not strictly define the implementation details of your scenario and you have quite a lot of freedom here. Choose what works best for you here - usually the simplest solution, but keep in mind DRY and SOLID principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, the answer is **any of the above**.

If the data used in the view model has a form *identical* to that of the model, you aren't doing yourself any favors by creating a `ConfigurationViewModel` class that is just a copy of the `Configuration` class.

As to adding, you can do it either way. Sometimes you want to do all your editing in the view model so you can "revert" the changes by not actually modifying the model. If that's not a concern, modifying the model first and propagating to the view model is just as valid of an approach.

All that being said, none of your approaches will violate MVVM. Pick what makes the most sense, especially semantically and for future maintenance. In general, I prefer simplicity to blind adherence to a principle such as "every data object needs a view model representation".

Comment: Ok, so my `ConfigurationListViewModel` will just have its internal `List<Configuration>` and will manage the exposure of its items to the view?

Comment: @user1722791 That's how would do it :). Caveat: If you need different data in the VM than the model, then you shouldn't go this route.

Comment: Thanks; just to know, if the internal `Configuration` would have needed its VM, the `ConfigurationListVM`would have had a list of `Configuration` or of `ConfigurationVM`?

Comment: @user1722791 `ConfigurationVM` (hopefully for obvious reasons :) )

Comment: @user1722791 - Except use ObservableCollection<Configuration> instead of List<Configuration> - that way you can directly bind to it if you ever need to and everything will just work.

Comment: This is exactly why we created Catel. We wanted to work with models, but be able to work with vm on a lower level. See https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Introduction+to+the+nested+user+controls+problem

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the `ConfigurationListViewModel` containing an `ObservableCollection<ConfigurationViewModel>` is the best (most flexible and cleanest) way.
Just for displaying selected items differently than non-selected items, it's useful when the items know about their selected state. And because selection is nothing the model should care about, you need a `ConfigurationViewModel` with an `IsSelected` property.

Updates (add, delete items) of the list (if triggered by the user/UI) should be done mainly by the model. (It's the model's responsibility to know how new item are initialized, for example.) And the ListViewModel should then change accordingly: create a viewmodel from the newly created model item or delete the viewmodel whose item was deleted in the model.

Comment: Imho, instead of `ConfigurationViewModel.IsSelected` property you can use `ConfigurationListViewModel.SelectedItem`. I wouln't create `ConfigurationViewMode`l in advance, just for case that at some point in future`Configuration` entity won't be easily presentable using xaml . Many times you can just expose the items from model and save yourself from creating viewmodel for each item, mappig from model to viewmodel and vice versa.

Comment: When you want to display selected items differently from non-selected items (say different foreground of font for example), then the `IsSelected` property gives you a way to access the selected state directly in the item template. To access the list's `SelectedItems` and determine the selected state of the current item inside the ItemTemplate is more complicated.
My point is: In WPF the item's view is created based on the item and therefore should depend on the item's properties and not an the list's properties.

Comment: There is ListBoxItem.IsSelected property that is sufficient for view logic. You can access it from DataTemplate using binding with relativesource, but ideally you should implement selection state only in ListBoxItem's Style resp ControlTemplate. In this case the pros of having ConfigurationViewModel are smaller than the cons I mentioned, however in other scenarios like TreeView, or editable Listbox (e.g. double click to rename) I would use it as well